# Input function in python

Tags: python

i am trying to write a simple input function that keeps repeating the first line until the conditions are met before running the next line

for example
if the first_name input in the code below is an integer it will run the print statement and repeat the repeat the first_name input request again until a string is provided.

i am stuck at the if statement and i dont know how to loop it, please help

I am a beginner just practicing

```
First_Name = str(input('First_Name: '))
if First_Name != str():
   print('please input a valid first name')
Last_Name = str(input('Last_Name: '))
if Last_Name != str():
   print('please input a valid last name')
Country1 = str(input('Country1: '))
if Country1 != str():
   print('please input a valid country name')
Age1 = int(input('Age1: '))
if Age1 != int():
   print('please input a number')

print(First_Name, Last_Name, Country1, Age1)
```

Comment: The `str()` function returns `''` which will only be true if you leave the names blank

Comment: you should use loop, for example `for` or `while`. this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/loops-in-python/) help to you

Answer (score 0):

input in python will always return a string, so there is no point in checking the type of the input. What you can check is if the string has a certain pattern. For instance you can check if it's all digits using isdigit().

If you want to check until a condition is matched you can use a while loop

```
while True:
    first_name = input('First_Name: ')
    if not first_name.isdigit():
        break
    print('please input a valid first name')
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down steps by steps :)

First thing first, the `input` built-in method always returns something of type`str`. You don't need to `cast` the input result into a string.

Now if I understand correctly you want to assess for each `if` statement that the input is of type `str`. You have to understand that `str()` will always return the empty string (`""`). To check this by yourself just type `str()` in a python console and see it for yourself.

Therefore when you write `FirstName == str()` it will always return `False` unless the user input is the empty quote.

To verify that the user input was an actual name and not for instance a number, you can use the built-in method `isdigit()` that returns a boolean indicating whether the parameter is a digit or not.

Try and run for each if statement :

```py
while True:
  FirstName = input('First_Name: ')
  if not FirstName.isdigit():
    # the name is a valid name and not a number
    break # exit the while loop and move on to the next if 
  print("Error ...")
  # the print only occurs if the previous if is not verified
  # meaning the name is not valid
```

Some usefull links :

[str() built-in method information](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str)

[loops over user inputs](http://introtopython.org/while_input.html#Using-while-loops-to-keep-your-programs-running)

[handling errors in python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `while loop` until condition is valid. To validate string `input` for `First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `Country1` you can use `isalpha()` function. It'll check input for alphabet characters and if it return `false`, `while loop` will continue to ask for `input`.

For the `Age1`, you can also use `while loop` or `try except` to validate wheter `input` is digit or integer. For this case, I suggest using `while loop` to check using `isdigit()`function, because this function only validate digits but exclude negative sign or decimal and then you only need to check if `input` is equals `0`. If those two condition is not fulfill then `while loop` will continue to ask for `input`, otherwise it'll break and execute the `print()` function

```
while True:
    First_Name = input('First_Name: ')
    if not First_Name.isalpha():
        print("please input a valid first name")
    else:
        break

while True:
    Last_Name = input('Last_Name: ')
    if not Last_Name.isalpha():
        print("please input a valid last name")
    else:
        break

while True:
    Country1 = (input('Country1: '))
    if not Country1.isalpha():
        print("please input a valid country")
    else:
        break

while True:
    Age1 = input('Age1: ')
    if Age1.isdigit() and int(Age1) > 0:
        break
    else:
        print('please input a number')
```

Output:

```
First_Name: 123
please input a valid first name
First_Name: Name2
please input a valid first name
First_Name: MyFirst
Last_Name: 098
please input a valid last name
Last_Name: Last1
please input a valid last name
Last_Name: MyLast
Country1: 007
please input a valid country
Country1: Country1
please input a valid country
Country1: USA
Age1: young
please input a number
Age1: 0
please input a number
Age1: -17
please input a number
Age1: 18

MyFirst MyLast USA 18

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

you can use this code :

```py
First_Name = str(input('First_Name: '))
while First_name == '':
    print('please input a valid first name')
    First_Name = str(input('First_Name: '))

Last_Name = str(input('Last_Name: '))
while Last_Name == '':
    print('please input a valid last name')
    Last_Name = str(input('Last_Name: '))

Country1 = str(input('Country1: '))
while Country1 == '':
    print('please input a valid country name')
    Country1 = str(input('Country1: '))

Age1 = str(input('Age1: '))
while Age1 == '':
    print('please input a number')
    Age1 = str(input('Age1: '))

print(First_Name, Last_Name, Country1, int(Age1))
```

Answer (score -2):

You can make a new function that allows passing a converting function, that will convert a string (resulted from calling `input()`) into the type that you want (e.g. `int`, or leave it as `str` by default). You can also pass a function that will check the converted value, and you will be requesting the user input until the check function returns `True`.

```
def input_until_valid(title, error_message, str_to_value_function=str, check_function=lambda v: True):
    # loop until the input value passes the check
    while True: 
        s = input(title)
        try:
          value = str_to_value_function(s)
        except:
          print(error_message)
          continue
          
        if check_function(value):
            return value
        else:
            print(error_message)

empty_check_function = lambda s: len(s) > 0
First_Name = input_until_valid(
  'First_Name: ', 
  "First name can't be empty", 
  check_function=empty_check_function)
Last_Name = input_until_valid(
  'Last_Name: ', 
  "Last name can't be empty", 
  check_function=empty_check_function)
Country1 = input_until_valid(
  'Country1: ', 
  "Country can't be empty", 
  check_function=empty_check_function)

Age1 = input_until_valid(
  'Age1: ',
  "Age must be a positive integer",
  str_to_value_function=int,
  check_function=lambda num: num > 0)

print(First_Name, Last_Name, Country1, Age1)
```

Output:

```json
First_Name: 
First name can't be empty
First_Name: 1
Last_Name: 
Last name can't be empty
Last_Name: 
Last name can't be empty
Last_Name: Smith
Country1: 
Country can't be empty
Country1: US
Age1: 
Age must be a positive integer
Age1: 3.2
Age must be a positive integer
Age1: -4
Age must be a positive integer
Age1: 100
1 Smith US 100
```

Notice that there's also a `try: except:` statement, which is needed because `int()` function throws an error when trying to convert invalid string values (e.g. empty string, or something non numerical). By wrapping the code with `try: except:` I instead show the error message and continue with the loop

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code, but the Fist Name , Last name and country inputs were also accepting integers. I wanted them to accept only strings. And i can see how lambda can also solve this for showing me that.

Comment: @AyodeleWilliams you can use  `empty_check_function = lambda s: len(s) > 0 and s.isalpha()`